# Unable to see charts for the d3 code. Error in console 't.apply is not a function'

Tags: d3.js, data-visualization

I am trying to use crossfilter.js and d3.js to generate brushes and charts to filter my data. The dates are in the format "2019-04-08T09:07:22.512Z" . I tried different ways to parse through the date and to generate the charts but am unable to do so . I get the following error in the console 't.apply is not a function'. Looking at the error I presume there is a problem with the render and renderAll functions.

d3 version 5.7.0

```
var cf = crossfilter(json);
            var all = cf.groupAll();
            var byAlertType = cf.dimension(function(p) {return p['alertType'];});
            var byDate = cf.dimension(function (p) { return p['created'].substring(0,10);});
            var byHour = cf.dimension(function (p) { return p['created'].substring(11,13);});
            var byTimezone = cf.dimension(function (p) { return p['created'].substring(30,39);});
            var groupByAlertType = byAlertType.group();
            var groupByDate = byDate.group();
            var groupByHour = byHour.group();
            var groupByTimezone = byTimezone.group();

            //data selected, counts by day date hour
            groupByAlertType.top(Infinity).forEach(function(p,i){
                console.log(p.key + ":" + p.value);
            });

            groupByDate.top(Infinity).forEach(function(p,i){
                console.log(p.key + ":" + p.value);
            });

            groupByTimezone.top(Infinity).forEach(function(p,i){
                console.log(p.key + ":" + p.value);
            });

            groupByHour.top(Infinity).forEach(function(p,i){
                console.log(p.key + ":" + p.value);
            });

          var charts = [
              barChart()
                  .dimension(byHour)
                  .group(groupByHour)
                  .x(d3.scaleLinear()
                      .domain([0,24])
                      .rangeRound([0, 10*24])),

              barChart()
                  .dimension(byDate)
                  .group(groupByDate)
                  .round(d3.timeDay.round)
                  .x(d3.scaleTime()
                      .domain([new Date(2019,4,1),new Date(2019,5,1)])
                      .rangeRound([0,10*30])),

              barChart()
                  .dimension(byAlertType)
                  .group(groupByAlertType)
                  .x(d3.scaleLinear()
                      .domain([0,24])
                      .rangeRound([0, 10*24])),


              barChart()
                  .dimension(byTimezone)
                  .group(groupByTimezone)
                  .x(d3.scaleLinear()
                      .domain([0,24])
                      .rangeRound([0, 10*24])),


          ];

          //charts as they appear in DOM

            const viz = d3.selectAll('.chart')
                .data([charts])


          // render initial list
            const list = d3.selectAll('.list')
                .data([alertList]);

            d3.selectAll('#total')
                .text((cf.size()));

            renderAll();


            function render(method){
                d3.select(this).call(method);
            }

            function renderAll() {
                viz.each(render);
                list.each(render);
                d3.select('#active').text(all.value());
            }

            window.filter = filters => {
                filters.forEach((d, i) => { charts[i].filter(d); });
                renderAll();
            };

            window.reset = i => {
                charts[i].filter(null);
                renderAll();
            };

            function alertList(div) {

            }

            function barChart() {
                if (!barChart.id) barChart.id = 0;

                let margin = { top: 10, right: 13, bottom: 20, left: 10 };
                let x;
                let y = d3.scaleLinear().range([100, 0]);
                const id = barChart.id++;
                const axis = d3.axisBottom();
                const brush = d3.brushX();
                let brushDirty;
                let dimension;
                let group;
                let round;
                let gBrush;

                function chart(div) {
                    const width = x.range()[1];
                    const height = y.range()[0];

                    brush.extent([[0, 0], [width, height]]);

                    y.domain([0, group.top(1)[0].value]);

                    div.each(function () {
                        const div = d3.select(this);
                        let g = div.select('g');

                        // Create the skeletal chart.
                        if (g.empty()) {
                            div.select('.title').append('a')
                                .attr('href', `javascript:reset(${id})`)
                                .attr('class', 'reset')
                                .text('reset')
                                .style('display', 'none');

                            g = div.append('svg')
                                .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
                                .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                                .append('g')
                                .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);

                            g.append('clipPath')
                                .attr('id', `clip-${id}`)
                                .append('rect')
                                .attr('width', width)
                                .attr('height', height);

                            g.selectAll('.bar')
                                .data(['background', 'foreground'])
                                .enter().append('path')
                                .attr('class', d => `${d} bar`)
                                .datum(group.all());

                            g.selectAll('.foreground.bar')
                                .attr('clip-path', `url(#clip-${id})`);

                            g.append('g')
                                .attr('class', 'axis')
                                .attr('transform', `translate(0,${height})`)
                                .call(axis);

                            // Initialize the brush component with pretty resize handles.
                            gBrush = g.append('g')
                                .attr('class', 'brush')
                                .call(brush);

                            gBrush.selectAll('.handle--custom')
                                .data([{ type: 'w' }, { type: 'e' }])
                                .enter().append('path')
                                .attr('class', 'brush-handle')
                                .attr('cursor', 'ew-resize')
                                .attr('d', resizePath)
                                .style('display', 'none');
                        }

                        // Only redraw the brush if set externally.
                        if (brushDirty !== false) {
                            const filterVal = brushDirty;
                            brushDirty = false;

                            div.select('.title a').style('display', d3.brushSelection(div) ? null : 'none');

                            if (!filterVal) {
                                g.call(brush);

                                g.selectAll(`#clip-${id} rect`)
                                    .attr('x', 0)
                                    .attr('width', width);

                                g.selectAll('.brush-handle').style('display', 'none');
                                renderAll();
                            } else {
                                const range = filterVal.map(x);
                                brush.move(gBrush, range);
                            }
                        }

                        g.selectAll('.bar').attr('d', barPath);
                    });

                    function barPath(groups) {
                        const path = [];
                        let i = -1;
                        const n = groups.length;
                        let d;
                        while (++i < n) {
                            d = groups[i];
                            path.push('M', x(d.key), ',', height, 'V', y(d.value), 'h9V', height);
                        }
                        return path.join('');
                    }

                    function resizePath(d) {
                        const e = +(d.type === 'e');
                        const x = e ? 1 : -1;
                        const y = height / 3;
                        return `M${0.5 * x},
                        ${y}A6,6 0 0 ${e} ${6.5 * x},
                        ${y + 6}V${2 * y - 6}A6,6 0 0 ${e} ${0.5 * x},${2 * y}ZM${2.5 * x},${y + 8}V${2 * y - 8}M${4.5 * x},${y + 8}V${2 * y - 8}`;
                    }
                }

                brush.on('start.chart', function () {
                    const div = d3.select(this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode);
                    div.select('.title a').style('display', null);
                });

                brush.on('brush.chart', function () {
                    const g = d3.select(this.parentNode);
                    const brushRange = d3.event.selection || d3.brushSelection(this); // attempt to read brush range
                    const xRange = x && x.range(); // attempt to read range from x scale
                    let activeRange = brushRange || xRange; // default to x range if no brush range available

                    const hasRange = activeRange &&
                        activeRange.length === 2 &&
                        !isNaN(activeRange[0]) &&
                        !isNaN(activeRange[1]);

                    if (!hasRange) return; // quit early if we don't have a valid range

                    // calculate current brush extents using x scale
                    let extents = activeRange.map(x.invert);

                    // if rounding fn supplied, then snap to rounded extents
                    // and move brush rect to reflect rounded range bounds if it was set by user interaction
                    if (round) {
                        extents = extents.map(round);
                        activeRange = extents.map(x);

                        if (
                            d3.event.sourceEvent &&
                            d3.event.sourceEvent.type === 'mousemove'
                        ) {
                            d3.select(this).call(brush.move, activeRange);
                        }
                    }

                    // move brush handles to start and end of range
                    g.selectAll('.brush-handle')
                        .style('display', null)
                        .attr('transform', (d, i) => `translate(${activeRange[i]}, 0)`);

                    // resize sliding window to reflect updated range
                    g.select(`#clip-${id} rect`)
                        .attr('x', activeRange[0])
                        .attr('width', activeRange[1] - activeRange[0]);

                    // filter the active dimension to the range extents
                    dimension.filterRange(extents);

                    // re-render the other charts accordingly
                    renderAll();
                });

                brush.on('end.chart', function () {
                    // reset corresponding filter if the brush selection was cleared
                    // (e.g. user "clicked off" the active range)
                    if (!d3.brushSelection(this)) {
                        reset(id);
                    }
                });

                chart.margin = function (_) {
                    if (!arguments.length) return margin;
                    margin = _;
                    return chart;
                };

                chart.x = function (_) {
                    if (!arguments.length) return x;
                    x = _;
                    axis.scale(x);
                    return chart;
                };

                chart.y = function (_) {
                    if (!arguments.length) return y;
                    y = _;
                    return chart;
                };

                chart.dimension = function (_) {
                    if (!arguments.length) return dimension;
                    dimension = _;
                    return chart;
                };

                chart.filter = _ => {
                    if (!_) dimension.filterAll();
                    brushDirty = _;
                    return chart;
                };

                chart.group = function (_) {
                    if (!arguments.length) return group;
                    group = _;
                    return chart;
                };

                chart.round = function (_) {
                    if (!arguments.length) return round;
                    round = _;
                    return chart;
                };

                chart.gBrush = () => gBrush;

                return chart;
            }

        };


    };
```

Comment: Can you provide error message?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: t.apply is not a function
    at Rt.call (d3.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDivElement.render (app111.js:120)
    at Rt.each (d3.min.js:2)
    at renderAll (app111.js:124)
    at XMLHttpRequest.req.onload (app111.js:116)

Comment: The json structure is as follows:[
    { "alertId": "some value","alertType": "","clusterKey": "","created": "2019-04-08T11:07:22.509+02:00[GMT+02:00]","criteria": {
            },
        "hitsSent": [],
        
        "pushToken": "",
        "ssoId": "",
        "tz": "GMT+2",
        "userAgent": "",
        "visitorId": ""
    },